# identify data with zero value in python

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I have data in following csv format

```
Date,State,City,Station Code,Minimum temperature (C),Maximum temperature (C),Rainfall (mm),Evaporation (mm),Sunshine (hours),Direction of maximum wind gust,Speed of maximum wind gust (km/h),9am Temperature (C),9am relative humidity (%),3pm Temperature (C),3pm relative humidity (%)
2017-12-25,VIC,Melbourne,086338,15.1,21.4,0,8.2,10.4,S,44,17.2,57,20.7,54
2017-12-25,VIC,Bendigo,081123,11.3,26.3,0,,,ESE,46,17.2,53,25.5,25
2017-12-25,QLD,Gold Coast,040764,22.3,35.7,0,,,SE,59,29.2,53,27.7,67
2017-12-25,SA,Adelaide,023034,13.9,29.5,0,10.8,12.4,N,43,18.6,42,27.7,17
```

The output for VIC sohuld be

```
S : 1
ESE : 1
SE : 0
N : 0
```

however i am getting output as

```
S : 1
ESE : 1
```

Thus would like to know, how can a unique function be used to include the other 2 missing results.  Below is the proram which calls a csv file

```
import pandas as pd
#read file
df = pd.read_csv('climate_data_Dec2017.csv')

#marker
value = df['Date']
date = value == "2017-12-26"
marker = df[date]

#group data
directionwise_data = marker.groupby('Direction of maximum wind gust')
count = directionwise_data.size()
numbers = count.to_dict()

for key in numbers:
  print(key, ":", numbers[key])
```

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand what you're trying to do here! Espicially that your code is producing nothing for the data sample you've provided. Can you elabortae further on what is it you're trying to do exaclty?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, i'm not sure what you're trying to get from this:
Your data sample has no "2017-12-26" records yet you're using it in your code, hence i presume for that sample, i'll change the code to "2017-12-25" just to see what is it producing, now that produces the exact thing you're expecting! Therefore i guess in your full data, you don't have records for "2017-12-26" for SE and N and therefore it's not being grouped, i suggest you create a unique set of the four directions you've in your df, then just count their occurances in a slice of your dataframe fo the needed date!

Or if all you want is how many records for each direction you have by date, why not just pivot it like below:

```
output = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns = 'Direction of maximum wind gust', aggfunc={'Direction of maximum wind gust':'count'}, fill_value=0)
```

**EDIT:**
Ok, so i wrote this real quick which should get you what you want, however you need to feed it which date you want:

```
import pandas as pd

#read csv
df = pd.read_csv('climate_data_Dec2017.csv')
#specify date
neededDate = '2017-12-25'
#slice dataframe to keep needed records based on the date
subFrame = df.loc[df['Date'] == neededDate].reset_index(drop=True)
#set count to zero
d1 = 0 #'S'
d2 = 0 #'SE'
d3 = 0 #'N'
d4 = 0 #'ESE'
#loop over slice and count directions
for i, row in subFrame.iterrows():
    direction = subFrame.at[i,'Direction of maximum wind gust']
    if direction == 'S':
        d1 = d1+1
    elif direction == 'SE':
        d2 = d2+1
    elif direction == 'N':
        d3 = d3+1
    if direction == 'ESE':
        d4 = d4+1
#print directions count
print ('S = ' + str(d1))
print ('SE = ' + str(d2))
print ('N = ' + str(d3))
print ('ESE = ' + str(d4))

S = 1
SE = 1
N = 1
ESE = 1
```